# mysql permissions with 1and1

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Does anyone know to give my user account access to a table?  I connect to the database fine but when I try to select the table it tells me Access denied for user 'dboxxxxx'@'%' to database.

I'm using basic php code

```
$con = mysqli_connect('xxxxxx.db.1and1.com', 'xxxxx', 'xxxxxx');

if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
else {echo 'success!';}

$selected = mysqli_select_db($con,'userTable');
if(!$selected){
    die ('cannot use db: '.mysqli_error($con));
}
```

There is no permissions options on the 1and1 phpmyadmin that I can see unless I'm totally missing it.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What error(s) are you getting? Check the type of user you are trying to connect as withen phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to supply `dboxxxxx` as a username, not `'dboxxxxx'@'%'`

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this code localy or within your server? The 1und1 firewall blocks connections from the foreign networks

Comment: I'm running this on my 1and1 server.

Answer (score -1):

You're probably not making the connection to the database correctly.

Try the changes I made. Note that I do not know that you are using classes and functions.

**UPDATE**

```
  $mysqli = new mysqli('xxxxx.db.1and1.com', 'xxxx', 'xxxx','xxxx'); 
    if(mysqli_connect_errno ())
    {
        printf('Unable to connect to database ' . mysqli_connect_error()); 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        $stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init(); 
        if(!$stmt)
        { 
            echo "init failed"; 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            $cmd = "insert into `userTable` (`oauthtoken`,`oauthtokensec`,`userid`,screenname`) VALUES ('?','?','?','?')"; 

            if($stmt->prepare($cmd))
            { 
                $stmt->bind_param('1','1','1','1'); 
                $stmt->execute(); 
                echo $stmt->affected_rows . " Row(s) Inserted"; 
                $stmt->close(); 
            }
            else
            { 
                echo "Prepare Failed"; 
            } 

        } $mysqli->close(); 
    }
```

Comment: I can do this but I can't select the TABLE after I do that and I can't insert any rows because of permissions.

Comment: I think I may be mixing my old mysql syntax with the newer mysqli stuff

Comment: how are you doing the SQL query?

Comment: $mysqli = new mysqli('xxxxx.db.1and1.com', 'xxxx', 'xxxx');

if(mysqli_connect_errno ()){
 printf('Unable to connect to database ' . mysqli_connect_error());
} else {
 
 $stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();
 if(!stmt){
  echo "init failed";
 } else {
  $cmd = "insert into userTable (oauthtoken,oauthtokensec,userid,screenname) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
  if($stmt->prepare($cmd)){
   $stmt->bind_param('1','1','1','1');
   $stmt->execute();
      
   echo $stmt->affected_rows . " Row(s) Inserted";
   
   $stmt->close();
   
  }else{
   echo "Prepare Failed";
  }
 }
 $mysqli->close();
}

Comment: Here is the new code I have tried to use.  It just seems like the 1and1 hosting mysql is not giving the correct rights

Comment: This answer absolutely irrelevant to the question

Comment: hi @intelwalk, did you find a solution, I need permission for my all database to one database user and trying to contact 1and1.com but they have very bad support team.

Comment: @MuhammadNadeem Nope I moved over to dreamhost shortly after this question due to the frustration.